# Laravel Eloquent 'where' query doesn't work with given id

Tags: php, laravel

In my Laravel project I send an ID through the router:

```
Route::get('dashboards/{dashboard}', 'DashboardController@show');
```

The ID in this case is `1`.

In my controller this query:

```
public function show(Dashboard $dashboard)
{
    $dash = Dashboard::find($dashboard);
    return $dash;
}
```

returns a dashboard with ID `1`. But when I use this query it shows nothing:

```
public function show(Dashboard $dashboard)
{
    $dash = DB::table('dashboards')->where('dashboardId', '=', $dashboard)->get();
    return $dash;
}
```

While using the same code but with `$dashboard` replaced with `1` it shows me all the dashboards with the same ID:

```
public function show(Dashboard $dashboard)
{
    $dash = DB::table('dashboards')->where('dashboardId', '=', 1)->get();
    return $dash;
}
```

Can someone explain to me why this isn't working? The query seems right to me.

Comment: Why are you trying to get a dashboard from the db when you have it already in `$dashboard`?

Comment: `$dashboard` only contains an ID @JonStirling

Comment: `$dashboard` is an object of `Dashboard`. you can't compare it with and id in `where` clause.

Comment: and why do you use `Dashboard` type in `show` function when it is actually type of int?

Comment: I thought that when I send the id in the router I could use it with $dashboard but this isn't the case?

Comment: you are casting the id to a `Dashboard` model when you accept it in the params, therefore you don't have to do the `$dash = ...` it is already done for you when you did `show(Dashboard $dashboard)`

Comment: From comments, please read the documentation on the code you're actually writing https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-model-binding

Comment: Found it, thanks @JonStirling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to write down eloquent if you use `Dashboard $dashboard`

```
public function show(Dashboard $dashboard)
{
   return $dashboard;
}
```

And if you want to use eloquent

```
public function show($dashboard)
{
    $dash = DB::table('dashboards')->where('dashboardId', '=', $dashboard)->get();
    return $dash;
}
```

Documentation : https://jenssegers.com/52/laravel-route-model-binding-is-awesome

Answer (score 3):

there can be 2 alternatives: 
first one, if you want to use Dashboard object

```
 public function show(Dashboard $dashboard){
$dash = DB::table('dashboards')->where('dashboardId', '=', $dashboard->id)->get();
    return $dash;
}
```

or second one you can give reference of id by passing $id which is $dashboard in your case

```
 public function show($dashboard){
$dash = DB::table('dashboards')->where('dashboardId', '=', $dashboard)->get();
    return $dash;
}
```

In your case if you are passing id through url then use straight second alternative mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

You are (unknowingly) using `Route Model Binding` to accept the dashboard id.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-model-binding

This converts the id you passed and gets the model for you.

Because you have `show(Dashboard $dashboard)` it will get the `Dashboard` model with the id 1 when you go to `/dashboards/1`

This means you do not need this line:

`$dash = DB::table('dashboards')->where('dashboardId', '=', $dashboard)->get();`

Because `$dashboard` that is accepted in the function parameter is already the `Dashboard` with the id 1.

--

If you wanted to manually get the dashboard then change the function param to `show($dashboardId)`

And then you can do this:

`$dash = DB::table('dashboards')->where('dashboardId', $dashboardId)->first();`

--

There is a really good Laracasts video about Route Model Binding here if you have access to them:

https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/9

Answer (score -3):

I think you should pass the **$dashboard->id** in the query

```
$dash = DB::table('dashboards')->where('dashboardId', '=', $dashboard->id)->get();
```